# Convert SQLite database to XML

Tags: xml, sqlite, converters

Is there any way to convert a `.sqlite` file to XML?

There exist [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9846216/3739455) that convert from XML to SQLite, but does are there tools that convert the other way, too?

Comment: With `.mode` you get either html or csv for free. Just redirect the output to a file. If I were to do it, I'd use `.mode line` and process the output in a small script to form some XML.

Comment: What is an example command? I get zero output doing `sqlite3 db.sqlite '.mode line'`.

Comment: Well the answer to your comment is in the script of your own answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I found a converter solution using `sqlite3`:

```
#!/bin/bash
SFILE="$1"
[ ! -f "$SFILE" ] && echo "$SFILE doesn't exist" 2>&1 && exit 2
for i in $(sqlite3 "$SFILE" '.table'); do
    echo -e ".mode csv\nselect * from $i;" | sqlite3 "$SFILE" > "$i".csv
done
```

start the script with `./script database.sqlite`

Creates for each table via `sqlite3 database.sqlite '.table'` a `tableentry.csv` file.

Now to convert csv to xml...