# Export Sqlite data to PDF or Excel

Tags: sqlite, pdf, pdf-generation, export-to-excel

Could anyone give me some guidance to export or convert an SQLite data to PDF and Excel in Xcode? Thanks you.

I have created an app and all records are kept in the SQLite data. So I want to export it to an excel file or pdf file.

Comment: Code? trials? ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There probably is a better way, but converting it to XML [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549190/convert-sqlite-database-to-xml) and then going from there should be easily accessible.